# Failed in build process in Unity

Tags: visual-studio, unity-game-engine, sdk, hololens

Every time I tried to build my project on unity, it failed with `Command failed, errorCode: 1` error. This project is for building application on HoloLens.

Unity editor Version:  [2020.3.24f1](https://unity.com/releases/editor/whats-new/2020.3.24)

VS Community: 2022

SDK version: 10.0.22621.0

here is the log:

```
Command failed, errorCode: 1
UnityEngine.Debug:Log (object)
Microsoft.MixedReality.Toolkit.Build.Editor.UwpAppxBuildTools/<Run>d__6:MoveNext () (at Library/PackageCache/com.microsoft.mixedreality.toolkit.foundation@a4d674c83201-1695838607315/Core/Utilities/BuildAndDeploy/UwpAppxBuildTools.cs:164)
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1<Microsoft.MixedReality.Toolkit.Utilities.ProcessResult>:SetResult (Microsoft.MixedReality.Toolkit.Utilities.ProcessResult)
Microsoft.MixedReality.Toolkit.ProcessExtensions/<StartProcessAsync>d__0:MoveNext () (at Library/PackageCache/com.microsoft.mixedreality.toolkit.foundation@a4d674c83201-1695838607315/Core/Extensions/ProcessExtensions.cs:38)
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1<Microsoft.MixedReality.Toolkit.Utilities.ProcessResult>:SetResult (Microsoft.MixedReality.Toolkit.Utilities.ProcessResult)
Microsoft.MixedReality.Toolkit.ProcessExtensions/<StartProcessAsync>d__1:MoveNext () (at
```

[image]
[image]
[image]

Can anyone tell me what went wrong here?

Thank you.

Comment: If you click the item that says "2 errors" it may have more details. You can also look in the editor.log file for all of the details.

Comment: user:920069 Yes, If I do that, it'll redirect to the visual studio by opening the .cs file. It never gives a straight answer like where this error occurred.

Comment: can you show the picture like above, but for the 2nd line down in the top half that says 2 errors - cos otherwise we have no idea what you're on about, always fix the first error not the last

Comment: Yes. This is the two errors:
```UnityEngine.Debug:Log (object)
Microsoft.MixedReality.Toolkit.ProcessExtensions/<>c__DisplayClass1_0:<StartProcessAsync>g__OnOutputDataReceived|2 (object,System.Diagnostics.DataReceivedEventArgs) (at Library/PackageCache/com.microsoft.mixedreality.toolkit.foundation@a4d674c83201-1695838607315/Core/Extensions/ProcessExtensions.cs:104)
System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitCallback:PerformWaitCallback ()
```

Comment: @BugFinder, I attached logged list as image in the post

Comment: thats the summeary in the top half, not the details .. in the top picture you have a list of stuff, the highlighted one shows the details in the bottom half, we need that of the first error line in your build.. eg not the last one as you originally did.

Comment: Thank you for the help. I solved this issue. the main issue was c++ code builder is unable to build c++ code.That the things is causing this issue. But it resolved now.